# How to store data with jQuery

Tags: jquery, store

How I can store the following function with .data?

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.sf-label-radio').text('');
        $('.sf-item-0').css('display', 'none');
    });
```

I read the documentation and did the following, but not working:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sf-label-radio').data(.text(''));
    $('.sf-item-0').data(.css('display', 'none'));
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding what you're trying to achieve here. `.data` is for storing **data**, like strings and integers.

Comment: This feels like an XY problem. Why do you need to store a function in an element's `data`? What are you trying to achieve? If you elabourate more on it, perhaps there's a better way to your question.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what you want. You can store/add attribute by attr() function

```
$(selecter).attr('attribute-name', value)
```